# Facing Issue during import process in content porter 2013 sp1

Tags: 2013-sp1, content-porter-2013

When I try to port component across different environment using content porter 2013 sp1, during import process I am getting the following exception during import process "Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Exceptions.LocalizableDataException: Stored Procedure failed
:SP_PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS-->Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException:ORA-29548:
Java system class reported:".
[image]
Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Please check the store procedure "SP_PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS" avaiable in CMS database. the issue seems to be stored procedure failed. Please refer this article(http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8398/stored-procedure-failed-sp-publications-find-conflicts-ora-06550-line-s-colu)