# Stored procedure failed: SP_PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS ORA-29548:

Tags: 2013-sp1, audience-manager, cm-db

In Tridion 2013 SP1 CME When I tried to make change in any field in the publication properties it throws below error. Even i stopped the Audience Manager services (windows services) still it gives the same issue:

> Stored procedure failed: SP_PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS ORA-29548:
>   Java system class reported: could not identify release specified in
>   classes.bin ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_XMLSAVE", line 3 ORA-06512: at
>   "TMS_OWN.PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS", line 22 ORA-06512: at line 1
>   StackTrace Information Details: at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.DataSession.OpenRecordsetByStoredProcedure(UserContext
>   userContext, String sProcName, Dictionary`2 parameters, Dictionary`2
>   outputParameters, Int32 timeoutSeconds) at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Dal.PublicationDal.FindBluePrintConflicts(IDictionary`2
>   publications) at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.DomainModel.Publication.AssertValidBluePrint(UserContext
>   userContext, IDictionary`2 bluePrintChainItems) at
>   Tridion.AudienceManagement.ContentManagerEvents.PublicationEvents.HandlerForSaveProcessed(Publication
>   subject, SaveEventArgs e, EventPhases phase)

I found below post related to this issue; let me know if the only solution is to re-ran the Tridion CM installer and unchecked Audience Manager to uninstall it Or there is some fix provided by Tridion for same.
[Stored procedure failed: SP_PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS ORA-06550: line %s, column %s:](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/8398/stored-procedure-failed-sp-publications-find-conflicts-ora-06550-line-s-colu)

Comment: Best option is to log a ticket with support. They will provide you the hotfix. As a workaround you can rerun the installer

Answer (score 5):

Seeing your issue and gone through with the link provided, there is a comment by Peter that powershell script could not get completed. Or might be the stored procedure got corrupted somehow.
 You can try executing upgrade script once with administrator privileges to restore the stored procedure in its correct form. 
Yes re-run the installer is also an option but for that database should be in the original state. 
 Also there is some database maintenance activity which you can perform but for this you should contact SDL Support to assist you.

Answer (score 1):

The stored procedure **SP_PUBLICATIONS_FIND_CONFLICTS** is actually part of the Audience Manager feature. When we ran the **Tridion 2013 SP1 installer**, we left it checked. For some reason this stored proc has an invalid object and as a result does not compile. The **Tridion Core Service** makes a call to this procedure when saving a Publication and since it couldn't compile an error was thrown.

To work around the issue, we have re-ran the Tridion CM installer and unchecked Audience Manager to uninstall it. Once this was completed and the CM server got restarted, new Publications can now be saved.

**As to why some of the stored procedure in the Audience Manager database could not compile, we're reaching out to Support for help here.**